# Insert custom html/javascript code on specific paragraph from a given php string using php

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla! website and I need to make the article default.php file to automatically add some custom code (Google Adsense or any other custom module generated content) after a specific tag (Eg.: second

or third ) of the article html code.

To be short, I have the standard php call for article text:

```
<div itemprop="articleBody">
    <?php echo $this->item->text; ?>
</div>
```

I want to use make an variable, let's call it `$basic_article`, which will be populated with `$this->item->text;`

I want to create a function that will count the number of paragraphs from `$basic_article` and insert a rendered Joomla! module position or even custom html code before or after the second, third or x paragraph of the string, then rewrap the string and print it or echo it.

Please, help me! Any advice is wellcome.

Comment: Generally you want to have what did you try?
Why did that not work? What was the problem?

Comment: I have tried this:
 `$new_article= str_replace('</p>', '', $basic_article);

$array = explode('<p>', $new_article);

$res = array_slice($array, 0, 3, true) +
    array("my_key" => "my_value") +
    array_slice($array, 3, count($array) - 1, true) ;

print_r($res);`, 
but the result only shows arrays. When I try to implode it, my custom key and value dissapears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this with advertising blocks by inputting a module position between set paragraphs.  Then you can assign which pages have that custom code (ie in module) on it or not. You can take this and customize to your needs.

Here is an example to put module between 1st and 2nd paragraphs.  You would replace your code with this

```html
<div itemprop="articleBody">
<?php
  $needle = "</p>";
  $length = strlen($needle);

  $this_article = $this->item->text;
  $pos1 = strpos($this_article, $needle);
  $pos2 = ($pos1!== 0 && strpos($this_article, $needle, $pos1 + $length)) ? strpos($this_article, $needle, $pos1 + $length): 0;

 $first_para = substr($this_article,0,$pos2);
 $rest_para = substr($this_article,$pos2 + $length); 
    echo $first_para;
    echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{loadposition inline-zone}'); 
    echo $rest_para;
?>  
</div>
```

You want to either do this in a template override in **/templates/MY_TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_content/article/default.php**

Or  make a custom article layout and put it in **/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/** . For example, I made copies of default.php and default.xml, renamed them inline.php and inline.xml and uploaded after customizing.
Make sure you assign the module you want interjected into that position name (inline-zone in example) and assign to the correct page(s).

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It's perfect! Now I'll have to find out a solution to set up the paragraph insert number.

Comment: I've studied more about this and I found this solution:
`       $ad1 = 'sometext';
        $ad2 = 'someothertext';
        $content = $this->item->text;
        $content_table = explode("<p>", $content);
        $content_table[0] .= JHtml::_('content.prepare', $ad1);
        if (array_key_exists(2, $content_table)) {
        $content_table[2] .= JHtml::_('content.prepare', $ad2);
        };
        $content = implode($content_table, "<p>");
        echo $content;`
I used if array_key_exists to search if the content text has more than 2 paragraphs to show ad2. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Be careful what HTML tags you put in the $ad1 and $ad2 variables though because it might throw off the page formatting.